# How can I implemented wait method from java to Objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wait and notify equivalent in Objective c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229319/wait-and-notify-equivalent-in-objective-c)

How can I implement wait method from java to Objective c?
I have code:  `wait(a);`
where a - variable of Integer.

Answer (score 1):

How about using dispatch semaphores from GCD? [Apple's docs on dispatch semaphores](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24) say the following:

> A dispatch semaphore is similar to a traditional semaphore but is generally more efficient. Dispatch semaphores call down to the kernel only when the calling thread needs to be blocked because the semaphore is unavailable. If the semaphore is available, no kernel call is made. For an example of how to use dispatch semaphores, see “Using Dispatch Semaphores to Regulate the Use of Finite Resources.”

What follows is an example from a card game I'm working on. The main thread waits until some condition (player finished his turn) is approved of.

```
   // a semaphore is used to prevent execution until the asynchronous task is completed ...

   dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);


   // player chooses a card - once card is chosen, animate choice by moving card to center of board ...

   [self.currentPlayer playCardWithPlayedCards:_currentTrick.cards trumpSuit:_trumpSuit completionHandler:^ (WSCard *card) {

       BOOL success = [self.currentTrick addCard:card];

       DLog(@"did add card to trick? %@", success ? @"YES" : @"NO");

       NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Card played by %@", _currentPlayer.name];
       [_messageView setMessage:message];

       [self turnCard:card];
       [self moveCardToCenter:card];


       // send a signal that indicates that this asynchronous task is completed ...

       dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);

       DLog(@"<<< signal dispatched >>>");
   }];


   // execution is halted, until a signal is received from another thread ...

   DLog(@"<<< wait for signal >>>");

   dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
   dispatch_release(sema);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [@synchronized](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocThreading.html) directive if you want to block another thread from accessing a critical section of code. If you just want to wait for the sake of waiting... you can use the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method on `NSObject`

Answer (score -3):

You can use the C function sleep

```
sleep(5);  // sleep for 5 seconds
```

If you want to wait without blocking the mainthread use this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(delayFunction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

Comment: Answers the direct question, but is an awful answer.  `sleep()` is never the right answer. :)

Comment: if I want wait for some variable?

Comment: The Java `wait()` waits indefinetly until the object is signalled using `notify()`.  It is **not** the same as sleep.

Comment: edited my answer to add a function that doesn't block the main thread. Agreed sleep() is not ideal, just thought it's what he was looking for :]

Comment: Blocking or not, it doesn't do the same thing.